# Is there any way in python to get live input from excel cells?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working to develop a user interface where user will be populating the inputs in an excel cell(every minute). So i want to link my python code with the excel cell so that python takes the input from the cell immediately as soon as something is entered in the cell. The processes i am aware of needs to save the file and re-run the code. But i dont want to save the excel file and re run, my code should be linked to excel and take live inputs. The cell is fixed, user will be changing the values in same cell every time and the duration is not fixed. User can change the input every minute,or no changes for hour.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219317/how-to-watch-excel-file-change-while-openpyxl-makes-changes).  Also, you could look for changes in file system, when excel file is saved: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes)